# Show dynamic data in multi language

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to convert existing site as multilingual which can support around 10-12 languages. 
I decided to prepare modular approach and create modular resource files in App_GlobalResources.

In this application 'Terms & Condition', 'Privacy Policy', 'News & events', 'FAQ' etc can be changed any time by Admin panel.
The admin will insert all the above data in english language. I want to show these data in the language as the user has selected.

So how can I show these data (which will come from database in english) in different languages at run time.

I have searched a lot for this, but could not get satisfied answer.

Please suggest how to overcome this issue.